# Função que troca a string

Tags: javascript

Eu queria uma função que recebesse uma string e devolvesse uma outra string com os caracteres deslocados 4 vezes.

Por exemplo:

`"aaaa"` retorna `"eeee"`

`"amor"` retorna `"eqsv"`

Obrigado.

Comment: O que você esteve tentando?

Comment: eu pensei em criar um vetor que guarda todos os chars, aí procurar um e devolver o da posição 4 pra frente. mas não acho que essa seja uma boa abordagem.

Comment: Se a função receber `zzzz` o que deve retornar?

Comment: se for `zzzz` deveria retornar `dddd`. o comportamento tem que ser cíclico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta somar no charCode a quantidade pretendida, e depois verificar a qual caracter esse número equivale:

```js
function trocar(){
  var s = document.getElementById('seutexto').value;
  var q = document.getElementById('quant').value;
  var newstring = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    //pega o charCode do caracter e soma
    var quant_troca = parseInt(q);
    var caracter = parseInt(s[i].charCodeAt(0));
    var aux = (caracter + quant_troca);
    //Verifica se ultrapassou os charcodes referentes a caracteres
    if(aux > 122)
    {
      //se passar do z, volta para o a
      aux = 97 + (quant_troca - (123 - caracter));
    }
    //concatena na nova string o caracter equivalente
    newstring += String.fromCharCode(aux);
  }
  alert(newstring);
}
```

```html
Digite o texto:<input id="seutexto" type="text"></input><br>
Digite a quantidade a deslocar<input id="quant" type="text"><br>
<br>
<button id="trocar" onclick="trocar()">Deslocar</button>
```

Comment: boa! não conheciia essa função! não ta 100% pq não tá cíclico, mas peguei a ideia

Comment: @J.Guilherme Arrumei para que seja cíclico